# Usb Communication Android Phone to Android Things

Tags: android, usb, raspberry-pi3, android-things, usb-otg

I am trying to setup *USB* communication serially with an *Android* phone to a *Raspberry Pi* loaded with *Android Things* (*USB OTG* cable).

- I am using an *OTG* cable to connect to the *Raspberry Pi*, making my *Android* phone the Host
- I understand how to use the *Android USB* Host API however it is the other side, that is, the code on the *Android Things Raspberry Pi* that I do not know what to do.

What does the code on the *Android Things Raspberry Pi* have to be to receive and react to *USB* serial communication from the Host *Android* phone? If possible, can you give a code example of how to react to a read command then provide specific information (say just a simply a string) back to the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Raspberry Pi 3B* cannot act as USB slave, only as USB host.

Some references:

- [Pi as a USB client](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22515/70348)
- [Using USB as a slave](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/4448/70348)
- [Raspberry pi 3 as USB device](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=152321) and many other over the Internet.

However, *RPi 3B* has [another capability](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/) which you may find of interest but, honestly, I am not sure if *Android Things* supports it.